# Does acquiring a new spellcasting focus require attunement?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting-focus, attunement

Our wizard goes to spend his quest reward to buy an expensive looking wand (because he was from a rich family).

At the shop, the rogue is caught shoplifting and the shopkeeper calls guards, so we have an unexpected encounter.

The wizard has already acquired the new wand. **Can he use the newly acquired wand right away, or does he need to attune to the wand first?**

The answer ideally should cover not only arcane focus, but also holy symbol, druidic focus, and such.

Related question, but not a duplicate since the focus in question is already complete/perfect: [Crafting an Improvised Spellcasting Focus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68624/crafting-an-improvised-spellcasting-focus) and [Using an Improvised Spellcasting Focus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68645/using-an-improvised-spellcasting-focus)

Comment: Is there any reason you think a spellcasting focus *does* require attunement?

Comment: Spellcasting focus is indeed look like a magic item, and some magic item requires attunement. Because spellcasting focus usually part of starting equipment, I suspect there is some sort of attunement that is not explicitly stated in the description.

Comment: Are you also asking of the focus in the PHB is a magic items? That should probably be another question (or clarify if the focus bought by your player was a magic item.)

Comment: @NautArch no, Im thinking of common focus, not magic item that explicitly requires attunement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No attunement is needed for a common focus

It is difficult to prove a negative but nothing in the rules suggests this. The description for an arcane focus simply states ([SRD p.67](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf), emphasis mine):

> An arcane focus is a special item— an orb, a crystal, a rod, a specially constructed staff, a wand-­like length of wood, or some similar item— designed to channel the power of arcane spells. **A sorcerer, warlock, or wizard can use such an item as a spellcasting focus**.

Other kinds of focus use similar wording. Attunement is a completely different mechanic related to magic items ([SRD p.206](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf), emphasis mine):

> Some magic items require a creature to form a bond with them before their magical properties can be used. **This bond is called attunement**, and certain items have a prerequisite for it.

Also note that Magic Items that require attunement explicitly indicate this requirment

Answer (score 2):

## No, it doesn't.

[Sdjz's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124032/43856) already makes a good argument, but I would like to add another conjecture:

**If a spellcasting focus needed attunement, spellcasters using it would be in a large disadvantage, as you can only attune to 3 magic items at the same time.** Obviously this implication is not enough to answer, but it should help to see that requiring attunement would lead to an awkward path.

> An item can be attuned to only one creature at a time and a creature can be attuned to no more than three
> magic items at a time.

Other than that, Attunement is a specific property and any item that has that property **explicitly states it**. The spellcasting focus does not. As an example, read the Druidic Focus

> **Druidic Focus**. A druidic focus might be a sprig of
> mistletoe or holly, a wand or scepter made of yew or
> another special wood, a staff drawn whole out of a living
> tree, or a totem object incorporating feathers, fur, bones,
> and teeth from sacred animals. A druid can use such an
> object as a spellcasting focus, as described in chapter 10.

Nowhere in the item it mentions anything about attunement, thus it does not require attunement. The same is true for every other (common/from PHB) spellcasting focus I'm aware of. In particular, the same **is true** for Holy Symbol and Arcane Focus.

As a final conjecture, an Arcane Focus (or any other spellcasting focus) is, mechanically, practically the same as a Component Pouch. I believe it's easy to see that requiring attunement to a Component Pouch makes little sense. From the first argument, if you require attunement to a Focus, you are just telling your players to use Component Pouches instead.