# How powerful is a high-level caster PC with barely any or no equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, cr-calculation

Let's assume your caster PC has crossed a high-level spellcaster and his minions the wrong way, or was overwhelmed by an army of guards. You are stripped of all equipment save for some clothes on your back and get exiled into the wild rather than imprisoned.

To substantiate "high level", let's say we're dealing with a character of high Tier 3/low Tier 4, around level 15/16, so no access to e.g. *Wish* spells.

How much power - specifically combat power, as your skill levels would be mostly unaffected - do you lose? A Wizard cannot cast spells of 1st level or higher without a spellbook, but can still cast cantrips for 3dx or 4dx damage; a Sorcerer needs material components or a focus at the bare minimum. Same goes for Warlocks.

Additionally, most casters have lower hit dice than martial classes.

If you were to balance an encounter for this PC, how much lower does he rank than if he had access to his usual arsenal of equipment and spells? I am aware that this is hard to answer, as most CR calculations revolve around a party, but that would broaden the question too much I suppose.

To address some comments: let's assume the caster has a "typical day's worth" of spells prepared (either prepared like cleric/wizard, or as a sorcerer his known=prepared spells) that are somewhat balanced between damage/CC/utility. They are expecting at least one encounter either with wild beasts or enemy forces before having time and shelter to craft an arcane focus/holy symbol/etc. as addressed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68624/crafting-an-improvised-spellcasting-focus/68626#68626).

To make the question specific enough with the addition of a specific class/race/level: let us assume a **level 15 Human wizard**. They have lost their spellbook, any magic items or equipment that could be used to feasably defend themselves (no daggers, armor, explorer's pack contents etc.), but are not fully naked, i.e., they still have clothes, shoes, etc. They expect encounters with either wild beasts and/or enemy forces before they can find refuge. If I use this [CR calculator](https://donjon.bin.sh/5e/calc/enc_size.html), a single 15th level character is expected to have, as an example, a *hard* encounter with monster(s) of the following CR

[image: Hard encounters table]

Some [CR 8 monsters](https://5thsrd.org/gamemaster_rules/monster_indexes/monsters_by_cr/#8) are Frost Giants, Young Green Dragons, or an Assassin. I really doubt a Wizard could solo one of these encounters under the described circumstances, unless they employ really advanced tactics, dumb luck, or have very favourable terrain. So, what metric could we use to determine an adjusted hard fight? (This situation is purely hypothetical, I'm not planning on buildung an encounter exactly like this, just trying to get a feel on how much gimping equipment removal is for a character)

Comment: [related Q&A that impacts on this answer heavily](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68626/22566) -  [This also](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68650/22566)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Depending on your spell choice, your level 15 Human Wizard is somewhere on the spectrum of entirely unaffected to only being able to cast cantrips. Where on this spectrum they fall depends on the specific spells they had prepared prior to the loss of equipment.

The general takeaway is that any analysis of power level of a caster, from a spellcasting perspective is going to heavily depend on the spells they have prepared/know. From a melee perspective, for the most part, they are not going to be able to perform as effectively, which can be a significant issue for some classes.

Due to the complexity of each class, subclass and the particulars of a build, this is going to be difficult to answer at a specific level, without significant constraints (which you have provided). I'll first, however, do a high level analysis, of what the effect of removing equipment is on the two areas of combat performance:

- Melee Combat
- Spellcasting Prowess

After doing this high-level analysis, I'll address your specific constraints of a level 15 Human Wizard with their clothes. Finally, I'll briefly mention Warlocks, as they have some special features that make them somewhat unique.

### Melee Combat

From the full casters perspective, the two classes most likely to be melee combatants are:

- Cleric
- Druid

The Cleric is significantly affected by the removal of equipment, as they have a tendency to be front line fighters, often taking the role of the "tank" in the party. They cannot fulfill this function if their armour is removed. They will also find it difficult to get a weapon they can wield (though they can supercharge any weapon they find using the Holy Weapon spell). But without armour melee combat is entirely out of the picture.

The Druid, in particular the Circle of the Moon Druid, can still function in combat due to their access to Wildshape. When they run out of Wildshape uses, they have a similar issue to the Cleric due to the loss of their armour.

The Half-Casters (Paladin/Ranger/Artificer) are much more affected by the removal of their equipment. For the Paladin, on top of the loss of armour, a large amount of the utility of the class lies in the use of spell slots to augment their melee damage (or to go NOVA). If they can find or scrounge a weapon, they can use the Elemental Weapon spell to buff up their base weapon attack. The Ranger is in a similar situation, in that a lot of their utility is tied up in being able to make attacks from a distance, which, without equipment is not possible.

The 1/3rd casters (Arcane Trickster and Eldritch Knight) are also pretty significantly affected, as similarly, they rely heavily on melee combat to enhance their utility, which, without armour, is pretty much taken away.

### Spellcasting Prowess

You make an important, incorrect assumption in your question, that casters, at a minimum, need an arcane focus or a component pouch. This is not the case for spells that do not require material components can be cast without either of these pieces of equipment.

You've also made the assumption that 1st level spells are always available to be cast, again, this assumption is not correct, only 1st level spells that have no material components can be cast.

So, depending on their preparation (and in one case their class), from a spellcasting perspective, they will either be severely affected (in that they will only be able to cast cantrips), or not affected at all.

The half and 1/3rd casters, are not designed around being able to spellsling for the whole of an encounter, and a number of these classes do not have access to cantrips, they would quickly run out of things to do other than run away.

That leaves us with analysing the full caster classes. Out of these, the two classes most affected by the removal of equipment, from a spellcasting perspective, are:

- Cleric
- Wizard

The spellcasting class *most* affected by this is clearly the Wizard, as they are the only class that gates what spells they *know* through a piece of equipment. Without their spellbook, they cannot prepare any new spells. That being said, the spells they had prepared before losing their spellbook are still fixed in their mind, and they can still cast them, provided they do not require material components.

After this are the Cleric, as *all* of the Cleric's 8th level spells require material components, and as a result they lose access to a whole level of spellcasting.

But beyond that, for the full casters, if they have chosen their spells to specifically mitigate this circumstance, they have options at pretty much every spellcasting level to choose either damaging or utility spells as appropriate (with the Cleric being the exception).

### Level 15 Human Wizard

By level 15, the Wizard has had 3 Ability Score Improvements. As a result we can assume, that by this stage, our wizard has both a 20 in Intelligence (which maximises their spell attack bonus and their spell save DC). So, using spells, from a pure to hit/controlling the field perspective, they can perform in battle as easily as they could without their spellbook (provided they have the right spells prepared). This means they will have, in their mind, prepared 20 (5 + 15) spells.

In the best case scenario, the wizard would be entirely unaffected. Looking at the list below, the most notable spell that they might be missing from their repertoire is Mage Armor. Looking in detail, however, at the material components of Mage Armor, it requires "a piece of cured leather" and this component *is not consumed by the casting!* You were generous enough to allow them shoes (particularly travelling shoes), which before the advent of modern clothing, were primarily made of cured leather. As a result, we can fulfil this material component at least. So the first thing our wizard would do is immediately cast Mage Armor, which lasts for 8 hours, to maximise their AC (in the event they are attacked), and thus enhance their survivability. They should also plan to recast this spell again after 8 hours have passed.

This leaves them with the following spell slots available "for combat":

- 8th level: 1
- 7th level: 1
- 6th level: 1
- 5th level: 2
- 4th level: 3
- 3rd level: 3
- 2nd level: 3
- 1st level: 2
- Cantrips: 5

If we give out 20 Intelligence Wizard some allowance for planning for this potential eventuality (ie they chose no spells that use material components that are difficult to find), then they will have the full compliment of spells available to them, and will be able to operate at full efficiency (although they won't be able to change their spells).

The 20 spells, from the list below, with the exception of Mage Armor, that I would have preprepared for them would be:

- 8th level:

  - Dominate Monster
- 7th level:

  - Teleport
- 6th level:

  - Otto's Irresistible Dance
- 5th level:

  - Cloudkill
  - Immolation
- 4th level:

  - Dimension Door
  - Storm Sphere
- 3rd level:

  - Counterspell
  - Dispel Magic
  - Phantom Steed
- 2nd level:

  - Alter Self
  - Knock
  - Mind Spike
  - Mirror Image
  - Misty Step
  - Scorching Ray
- 1st level:

  - Detect Magic
  - Mage Armor
  - Magic Missile
  - Shield
- Cantrips:

  - Create Bonfire
  - Encode Thoughts
  - Fire Bolt
  - Mage Hand
  - Prestidigitation

With this set of prepared spells, I'd judge that the spellcaster is approximately as strong as they are likely to be if they had all of their equipment available to them.

To be honest though, if I'm that spellcaster, with that set of spells, I would use teleport to go to a teleportation circle I know straight away, and establish a line of credit with whoever I know and am friendly with to buy new equipment while I plot my revenge. I'm a 15th level spellcaster. I've gotten myself to the stage where "the fate of the nation, or the world" (*DMG Tiers of Play*) have been in the balance during my adventures. I have almost certainly made powerful allies, upon whom I can rely to get myself back to a good level of equipment almost immediately.

### A brief aside on Warlocks

Warlocks...are tough, as they are the spellcasting class with both the least flexibility, but also, potentially the most ability to last a full adventuring day without needing to resort to melee combat. That being said, clearly the subclasses of the Warlock focused on being a front-line fighter, like the Hexblade Warlock, take a significant downstep in power due to a large element of the balance baked into the subclass being removed.

That being said, if the Warlock has taken the Pact of the Blade "Pact Boon" can perform as well in melee combat from an offensive point of view, due to the fact they cannot be disarmed of their weapon (they can resummon it at any time). They still have the armour issue

From a spellcasting perspective though, they have access to their most important battlefield spell, Eldritch Blast, which can be augmented to be significantly more powerful than a regular cantrip, through their Invocations.

They also have access to the bulk of their spells which they need spellslots or the Mystic Arcanum feature to cast. So, by and large, Warlocks are probably one of the least affected classes.

### Table of Available spells by level

The full list (as of 2020-09-06) of non-material component spells are listed below, broken out by class. I've neglected both the Arcane Trickster and the Eldritch Knight from the list as they both use a subset of the Wizard spell list, so the Wizard list should suffice. These lists are compile-able, using the spell search feature D&D Beyond, without access to a subscription by specifying that material components are excluded in the filter list.

I have included these lists in part as a reference, should you wish to compile your own lists, or a visual demonstration of how each spellcasting class is affected by losing their equipment.

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
Level & Artificer & Bard & Cleric & Druid & Paladin & Ranger & Sorcerer & Warlock & Wizard \\
\hline
8th & N/A & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Dominate Monster} \\
\text{Glibness} \\
\text{Mind Blank} \\
\text{Power Word Stun} \\
\end{array}& N/A & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Animal Shapes} \\
\text{Tsunami} \\
\end{array}& N/A&  N/A& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Dominate Monster} \\
\text{Incendiary Cloud} \\
\text{Power Word Stun} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Demiplane} \\
\text{Dominate Monster} \\
\text{Glibness} \\
\text{Power Word Stun} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Demiplane} \\
\text{Dominate Monster} \\
\text{Illusory Dragon} \\
\text{Incendiary Cloud} \\
\text{Maze} \\
\text{Mind Blank} \\
\text{Power Word Stun} \\
\end{array} \\
\hline
7th & N/A & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Etherealness} \\
\text{Mirage Arcane} \\
\text{Teleport} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Conjure Celestial} \\
\text{Divine Word} \\
\text{Etherealness} \\
\text{Fire Storm} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Fire Storm} \\
\text{Mirage Arcane} \\
\end{array} &  N/A&  N/A& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Crown of Stars} \\
\text{Etherealness} \\
\text{Finger of Death} \\
\text{Fire Storm} \\
\text{Power Word Pain} \\
\text{Prismatic Spray} \\
\text{Teleport} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Crown of Stars} \\
\text{Etherealness} \\
\text{Finger of Death} \\
\text{Power Word Pain} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Crown of Stars} \\
\text{Etherealness} \\
\text{Finger of Death} \\
\text{Mirage Arcane} \\
\text{Power Word Pain} \\
\text{Prismatic Spray} \\
\text{Teleport} \\
\end{array} \\
\hline
6th & N/A & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Eyebite} \\
\text{Otto's Irresistible Dance} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blade Barrier} \\
\text{Harm} \\
\text{Heal} \\
\text{Planar Ally} \\
\text{Word of Recall} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Bones of the Earth} \\
\text{Conjure Fey} \\
\text{Heal} \\
\text{Investiture of Flame} \\
\text{Investiture of Ice} \\
\text{Investiture of Stone} \\
\text{Investiture of Wind} \\
\text{Primordial Ward} \\
\text{Transport via Plants} \\
\end{array} &  N/A&  N/A& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Arcane Gate} \\
\text{Eyebite} \\
\text{Investiture of Flame} \\
\text{Investiture of Ice} \\
\text{Investiture of Stone} \\
\text{Investiture of Wind} \\
\text{Mental Prison} \\
\text{Scatter} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Arcane Gate} \\
\text{Conjure Fey} \\
\text{Eyebite} \\
\text{Investiture of Flame} \\
\text{Investiture of Ice} \\
\text{Investiture of Stone} \\
\text{Investiture of Wind} \\
\text{Mental Prison} \\
\text{Scatter} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Arcane Gate} \\
\text{Eyebite} \\
\text{Investiture of Flame} \\
\text{Investiture of Ice} \\
\text{Investiture of Stone} \\
\text{Investiture of Wind} \\
\text{Mental Prison} \\
\text{Otto's Irresistible Dance} \\
\text{Scatter} \\
\end{array} \\
\hline
5th & N/A & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Animate Objects} \\
\text{Dominate Person} \\
\text{Geas} \\
\text{Mass Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Mislead} \\
\text{Modify Memory} \\
\text{Seeming} \\
\text{Skill Empowerment} \\
\text{Synaptic Static} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Contagion} \\
\text{Geas} \\
\text{Holy Weapon} \\
\text{Mass Cure Wounds} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Antilife Shell} \\
\text{Commune with Nature} \\
\text{Contagion} \\
\text{Control Winds} \\
\text{Geas} \\
\text{Mass Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Tree Stride} \\
\text{Wrath of Nature} \\
\end{array} &  N/A&  N/A& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Animate Objects} \\
\text{Cloudkill} \\
\text{Control Winds} \\
\text{Dominate Person} \\
\text{Enervation} \\
\text{Far Step} \\
\text{Immolation} \\
\text{Seeming} \\
\text{Skill Empowerment} \\
\text{Synaptic Static} \\
\text{Telekinesis} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Contact Other Plane} \\
\text{Danse Macabre} \\
\text{Enervation} \\
\text{Far Step} \\
\text{Synaptic Static} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Animate Objects} \\
\text{Cloudkill} \\
\text{Contact Other Plane} \\
\text{Control Winds} \\
\text{Danse Macabre} \\
\text{Dominate Person} \\
\text{Enervation} \\
\text{Far Step} \\
\text{Geas} \\
\text{Immolation} \\
\text{Mislead} \\
\text{Modify Memory} \\
\text{Seeming} \\
\text{Skill Empowerment} \\
\text{Synaptic Static} \\
\text{Telekinesis} \\
\end{array} \\
\hline
4th &
 \begin{array}{r}
 \text{Elemental Bane} \\
 \text{Fabricate} \\
 \end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Charm Monster} \\
\text{Compulsion} \\
\text{Dimension Door} \\
\text{Greater Invisibility} \\
\text{Intellect Fortress (UA)} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Death Ward} \\
\text{Guardian of Faith} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blight} \\
\text{Charm Monster} \\
\text{Conjure Minor Elementals} \\
\text{Dominate Beast} \\
\text{Elemental Bane} \\
\text{Giant Insect} \\
\text{Grasping Vine} \\
\text{Guardian of Nature} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Aura of Life} \\
\text{Aura of Purity} \\
\text{Death Ward} \\
\text{Find Greater Steed} \\
\text{Staggering Smite} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Grasping Vine} \\
\text{Guardian of Nature} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blight} \\
\text{Charm Monster} \\
\text{Dimension Door} \\
\text{Dominate Beast} \\
\text{Greater Invisibility} \\
\text{Intellect Fortress (UA)} \\
\text{Sickening Radiance} \\
\text{Storm Sphere} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blight} \\
\text{Charm Monster} \\
\text{Dimension Door} \\
\text{Elemental Bane} \\
\text{Sickening Radiance} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blight} \\
\text{Charm Monster} \\
\text{Conjure Minor Elementals} \\
\text{Dimension Door} \\
\text{Elemental Bane} \\
\text{Fabricate} \\
\text{Greater Invisibility} \\
\text{Intellect Fortress (UA)} \\
\text{Phantasmal Killer} \\
\text{Sickening Radiance} \\
\text{Storm Sphere} \\
\end{array} \\ 
\hline
3rd & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blink} \\
\text{Create Food and Water} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Elemental Weapon} \\
\text{Flame Arrows} \\
\text{Protection from Energy} \\
\text{Tiny Servant} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Bestow Curse} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Enemies Abound} \\
\text{Fast Friends} \\
\text{Motivational Speech} \\
\text{Plant Growth} \\
\text{Speak with Plants} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Beacon of Hope} \\
\text{Bestow Curse} \\
\text{Create Food and Water} \\
\text{Daylight} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Fast Friends} \\
\text{Life Transference} \\
\text{Mass Healing Word} \\
\text{Meld into Stone} \\
\text{Motivational Speech} \\
\text{Protection from Energy} \\
\text{Remove Curse} \\
\text{Spirit Shroud (UA)} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Call Lightning} \\
\text{Conjure Animals} \\
\text{Daylight} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Flame Arrows} \\
\text{Meld into Stone} \\
\text{Plant Growth} \\
\text{Protection from Energy} \\
\text{Speak with Plants} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Aura of Vitality} \\
\text{Blinding Smite} \\
\text{Create Food and Water} \\
\text{Crusader’s Mantle} \\
\text{Daylight} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Elemental Weapon} \\
\text{Remove Curse} \\
\text{Spirit Shroud (UA)} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Conjure Animals} \\
\text{Daylight} \\
\text{Flame Arrows} \\
\text{Lightning Arrow} \\
\text{Plant Growth} \\
\text{Protection from Energy} \\
\text{Speak with Plants} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blink} \\
\text{Counterspell} \\
\text{Daylight} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Enemies Abound} \\
\text{Flame Arrows} \\
\text{Protection from Energy} \\
\text{Thunder Step} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Counterspell} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Enemies Abound} \\
\text{Remove Curse} \\
\text{Spirit Shroud (UA)} \\
\text{Thunder Step} \\
\text{Vampiric Touch} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Bestow Curse} \\
\text{Blink} \\
\text{Counterspell} \\
\text{Dispel Magic} \\
\text{Enemies Abound} \\
\text{Fast Friends} \\
\text{Flame Arrows} \\
\text{Life Transference} \\
\text{Phantom Steed} \\
\text{Protection from Energy} \\
\text{Remove Curse} \\
\text{Spirit Shroud (UA)} \\
\text{Thunder Step} \\
\text{Tiny Servant} \\
\text{Vampiric Touch} \\
\end{array} \\
\hline
2nd & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Alter Self} \\
\text{Blur} \\
\text{Lesser Restoration} \\
\text{Magic Weapon} \\
\text{Protection from Poison} \\
\text{Pyrotechnics} \\
\text{Skywrite} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blindness/Deafness} \\
\text{Calm Emotions} \\
\text{Crown of Madness} \\
\text{Enthrall} \\
\text{Knock} \\
\text{Lesser Restoration} \\
\text{Pyrotechnics} \\
\text{Silence} \\
\text{Skywrite} \\
\text{Warding Wind} \\
\text{Zone of Truth} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blindness/Deafness} \\
\text{Calm Emotions} \\
\text{Find Traps} \\
\text{Lesser Restoration} \\
\text{Prayer of Healing} \\
\text{Protection from Poison} \\
\text{Silence} \\
\text{Spiritual Weapon} \\
\text{Zone of Truth} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Beast Sense} \\
\text{Earthbind} \\
\text{Find Traps} \\
\text{Healing Spirit} \\
\text{Lesser Restoration} \\
\text{Protection from Poison} \\
\text{Skywrite} \\
\text{Warding Wind} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Branding Smite} \\
\text{Find Steed} \\
\text{Lesser Restoration} \\
\text{Magic Weapon} \\
\text{Protection from Poison} \\
\text{Zone of Truth} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Beast Sense} \\
\text{Find Traps} \\
\text{Healing Spirit} \\
\text{Lesser Restoration} \\
\text{Protection from Poison} \\
\text{Silence} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Alter Self} \\
\text{Blindness/Deafness} \\
\text{Blur} \\
\text{Crown of Madness} \\
\text{Earthbind} \\
\text{Knock} \\
\text{Mind Spike} \\
\text{Mind Thrust (UA)} \\
\text{Mirror Image} \\
\text{Misty Step} \\
\text{Pyrotechnics} \\
\text{Scorching Ray} \\
\text{Shadow Blade} \\
\text{Warding Wind} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Crown of Madness} \\
\text{Earthbind} \\
\text{Enthrall} \\
\text{Flock of Familiars} \\
\text{Mind Spike} \\
\text{Mirror Image} \\
\text{Misty Step} \\
\text{Ray of Enfeeblement} \\
\text{Shadow Blade} \\
\end{array} & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Alter Self} \\
\text{Blindness/Deafness} \\
\text{Blur} \\
\text{Crown of Madness} \\
\text{Earthbind} \\
\text{Flock of Familiars} \\
\text{Knock} \\
\text{Magic Weapon} \\
\text{Mind Spike} \\
\text{Mind Thrust (UA)} \\
\text{Mirror Image} \\
\text{Misty Step} \\
\text{Pyrotechnics} \\
\text{Ray of Enfeeblement} \\
\text{Scorching Ray} \\
\text{Shadow Blade} \\
\text{Skywrite} \\
\text{Warding Wind} \\
\end{array} \\
\hline
1st & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Absorb Elements} \\
\text{Catapult} \\
\text{Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Disguise Self} \\
\text{Expeditious Retreat} \\
\text{Faerie Fire} \\
\text{Purify Food and Drink} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Charm Person} \\
\text{Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Disguise Self} \\
\text{Dissonant Whispers} \\
\text{Distort Value} \\
\text{Earth Tremor} \\
\text{Faerie Fire} \\
\text{Healing Word} \\
\text{Heroism} \\
\text{Speak with Animals} \\
\text{Thunderwave} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Command} \\
\text{Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Detect Evil and Good} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Guiding Bolt} \\
\text{Healing Word} \\
\text{Inflict Wounds} \\
\text{Purify Food and Drink} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Absorb Elements} \\
\text{Charm Person} \\
\text{Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Earth Tremor} \\
\text{Entangle} \\
\text{Faerie Fire} \\
\text{Fog Cloud} \\
\text{Healing Word} \\
\text{Purify Food and Drink} \\
\text{Speak with Animals} \\
\text{Thunderwave} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Command} \\
\text{Compelled Duel} \\
\text{Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Detect Evil and Good} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Divine Favor} \\
\text{Heroism} \\
\text{Purify Food and Drink} \\
\text{Searing Smite} \\
\text{Thunderous Smite} \\
\text{Wrathful Smite} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Absorb Elements} \\
\text{Cure Wounds} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Ensnaring Strike} \\
\text{Fog Cloud} \\
\text{Hail of Thorns} \\
\text{Hunter's Mark} \\
\text{Speak with Animals} \\
\text{Zephyr Strike} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Absorb Elements} \\
\text{Burning Hands} \\
\text{Catapult} \\
\text{Chaos Bolt} \\
\text{Charm Person} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Disguise Self} \\
\text{Distort Value} \\
\text{Earth Tremor} \\
\text{Expeditious Retreat} \\
\text{Fog Cloud} \\
\text{Magic Missile} \\
\text{Ray of Sickness} \\
\text{Shield} \\
\text{Thunderwave} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Arms of Hadar} \\
\text{Cause Fear} \\
\text{Charm Person} \\
\text{Distort Value} \\
\text{Expeditious Retreat} \\
\text{Hellish Rebuke} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Absorb Elements} \\
\text{Burning Hands} \\
\text{Catapult} \\
\text{Cause Fear} \\
\text{Charm Person} \\
\text{Detect Magic} \\
\text{Disguise Self} \\
\text{Distort Value} \\
\text{Earth Tremor} \\
\text{Expeditious Retreat} \\
\text{Fog Cloud} \\
\text{Magic Missile} \\
\text{Ray of Sickness} \\
\text{Shield} \\
\text{Thunderwave} \\
\end{array}\\
\hline
Cantrip & N/A & \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blade Ward} \\
\text{Encode Thoughts (Dimir Guild spell)} \\
\text{Mage Hand} \\
\text{Prestidigitation} \\
\text{Thunderclap} \\
\text{True Strike} \\
\text{Vicious Mockery} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Encode Thoughts (Dimir Guild spell)} \\
\text{Guidance} \\
\text{Sacred Flame} \\
\text{Spare the Dying} \\
\text{Thaumaturgy} \\
\text{Toll the Dead} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Control Flames} \\
\text{Create Bonfire} \\
\text{Druidcraft} \\
\text{Encode Thoughts (Dimir Guild spell)} \\
\text{Frostbite} \\
\text{Guidance} \\
\text{Gust} \\
\text{Magic Stone} \\
\text{Mold Earth} \\
\text{Poison Spray} \\
\text{Primal Savagery} \\
\text{Produce Flame} \\
\text{Shape Water} \\
\text{Thunderclap} \\
\end{array}& N/A& N/A& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Acid Splash} \\
\text{Blade Ward} \\
\text{Chill Touch} \\
\text{Control Flames} \\
\text{Create Bonfire} \\
\text{Encode Thoughts (Dimir Guild spell)} \\
\text{Fire Bolt} \\
\text{Frostbite} \\
\text{Gust} \\
\text{Lightning Lure} \\
\text{Mage Hand} \\
\text{Mind Sliver (UA)} \\
\text{Mold Earth} \\
\text{Poison Spray} \\
\text{Prestidigitation} \\
\text{Ray of Frost} \\
\text{Shape Water} \\
\text{Shocking Grasp} \\
\text{Sword Burst} \\
\text{Thunderclap} \\
\text{True Strike} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Blade Ward} \\
\text{Chill Touch} \\
\text{Create Bonfire} \\
\text{Eldritch Blast} \\
\text{Encode Thoughts (Dimir Guild spell)} \\
\text{Frostbite} \\
\text{Lightning Lure} \\
\text{Mage Hand} \\
\text{Magic Stone} \\
\text{Mind Sliver (UA)} \\
\text{Poison Spray} \\
\text{Prestidigitation} \\
\text{Sword Burst} \\
\text{Thunderclap} \\
\text{Toll the Dead} \\
\text{True Strike} \\
\end{array}& \begin{array}{r}
\text{Acid Splash} \\
\text{Blade Ward} \\
\text{Chill Touch} \\
\text{Control Flames} \\
\text{Create Bonfire} \\
\text{Encode Thoughts (Dimir Guild spell)} \\
\text{Fire Bolt} \\
\text{Frostbite} \\
\text{Gust} \\
\text{Lightning Lure} \\
\text{Mage Hand} \\
\text{Mind Sliver (UA)} \\
\text{Mold Earth} \\
\text{Poison Spray} \\
\text{Prestidigitation} \\
\end{array}\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: D&D Beyond lists *encode thoughts* as a wizard spell, but it isn't one by RAW. You have to be a spellcaster in a specific Ravnica guild (PC background) to gain access to it.

Comment: @raithyn fair point, though for other settings your DM may allow it to be taken (since the guild doesn't exist elsewhere). I'll remove it from the list

Comment: @raithyn I canged my mind slightly and added it to all of the classes that have access to cantrip, and clarified that it's a Dimir Guild spell

Comment: That's certainly fair. And I as a DM would tend to allow any spellcaster access to it outside Ravnica--it's a cool spell that's underused--but I think the clarification is helpful for anyone who doesn't have that book. D&D Beyond created some confusion by trying to fit it into their existing system instead of adapting as they later did for the Wildemount spells.